# Hole in a cube with boolean

Tags: modeling

I have the same problem like this:
[Boolean Issue: hole in mesh is.... strange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111228/boolean-issue-hole-in-mesh-is-strange)

I need to cut a hole in a cube. I'm trying to use a Boolean modifier.

It doesn't cut but extrude actually a hole from the cube.

I'm in Blender 2.8. So there is no `Solver` option in Boolean modifier.

How is it better to cut a hole in a cube in 2.8?

[image]

Comment: Make the cube manifold by filling in its missing faces.

Comment: ^ Solidify modifier is one of the approaches for that.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the manual and found that it is supposed to work that way. you can instead go to user preferences and tick the loop tool add-on.

then subdivide the surfaces -> select the faces you want -> edit on the side panel ->
loop tools drop-down -> click on circle -> later you may delete those faces.
Add more subdivisions if you want a more accurate circle or add a subdivision modifier(you might want to clean up a bit by adding edge-loops.

[image]

[image]

[image]